# Where does wolfram script store the command history? (like .bashrc)

Tags: scripting, free-wolfram-engine

I'm imagining there is a file like bashrc, because I've noticed the wolfram Script on windows remembers my command history. I'm using `12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 5, 2021)`

When I open Wolfram Engine, the wolfram script terminal opens up. Then, if I hit the up arrow on my keyboard, commands I entered in a previous session appear. I can hit the up arrow maybe 5 times before it stops getting new commands.

Where is this information stored? Is there a bashrc type file? Is it hidden within the kernel?

Comment: Take a look in `<Install drive letter>:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\term.history`

Comment: `FileNames["term.history", $UserBaseDirectory]`